# How do I get 3d tiles on a row and zoom effect on hover?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to get 3d tiles on a row and I want to zoom on hover and it should be responsive. I am trying to get the below look and feel,

[image]

Am using bootstrap 3 and Wordpress. Please guide me how can I achieve this

https://www.overdrive.com

```css
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->
    <div class="container">
            <div class ="row">
                <img src="https://img.fireden.net/co/image/1484/60/1484607166775.jpg">
                <img src="https://khms0.googleapis.com/kh?v=852&hl=en-US&x=2358&y=3247&z=13">
                <img src="https://img.fireden.net/co/image/1484/60/1484607166775.jpg">
                <img src="https://khms0.googleapis.com/kh?v=852&hl=en-US&x=2358&y=3247&z=13">
                <img src="https://img.fireden.net/co/image/1484/60/1484607166775.jpg">
               
                
            </div>

         
        </div>
    <div class="container">
    <hr>
      <div class="row">
      
        <div class="
        img-hover" style="float:left">
        
          <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/300">
          
                <img class="https://khms0.googleapis.com/kh?v=852&hl=en-US&x=2358&y=3247&z=13">
          <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/300">

        
        </div>
      
      </div>
      
    </div>
```

I have added both methods which I tried. I am unable to get that. Please help

Comment: Please show us your code and what you have tried.

Comment: Am really sorry @CarstenLøvboAndersen , am new to stackoverfllow.. so not included the code.. I will update in a moment

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen, I have update the question with my code

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen, can you please suggest me how can I achieve the required UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, I leave RWD support to you ;)

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

ul {
  margin: 30px auto;
}

ul li {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 -27px;
  position: relative;
}

ul li:hover {
  z-index: 5;
}

ul li img {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: all 400ms ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul li img:hover {
  max-width: 193px !important;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 25px #000;
}

ul li:nth-child(1) img {
  max-width: 153px;
  z-index: 1;
}

ul li:nth-child(2) img {
  max-width: 173px;
  z-index: 2;
}

ul li:nth-child(3) img {
  max-width: 193px;
  z-index: 3;
}

ul li:nth-child(4) img {
  max-width: 173px;
  z-index: 2;
}

ul li:nth-child(5) img {
  max-width: 153px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <ul class="list-inline">
      <li class="list-inline-item"><img src="https://img.fireden.net/co/image/1484/60/1484607166775.jpg"></li>
      <li class="list-inline-item"><img src="https://khms0.googleapis.com/kh?v=852&hl=en-US&x=2358&y=3247&z=13"></li>
      <li class="list-inline-item"><img src="https://img.fireden.net/co/image/1484/60/1484607166775.jpg"></li>
      <li class="list-inline-item"><img src="https://khms0.googleapis.com/kh?v=852&hl=en-US&x=2358&y=3247&z=13"></li>
      <li class="list-inline-item"><img src="https://img.fireden.net/co/image/1484/60/1484607166775.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Can it be responsive in all screens?

Comment: As I wrote RWD, I leave it to you ;). Add rwd support and hide individual nth-child at different resolutions. Follow the example [https://www.overdrive.com](https://www.overdrive.com) you provided is very legible.